# Aurelia Unit Test Custom Element Binding - propertyNameChanged does not fire?

Tags: javascript, typescript, aurelia

I am trying to test custom element which has property `pageNumber` and change-event handles `pageNumberChanged()` defined.

```js
@autoinject
export class Pagination {
    @bindable
    public pageNumber: number | undefined;

    public pageNumberChanged() {
        // recalculate pagination...
    }

   // more code...
}
```

Change handler is triggered and working in the application, but if I want to unit test custom element, handler is never triggered.

Using `setTimeout` delays assertion, so that ViewModel has time to update, but even then, handler which re-calculates `pages` array is never executed.

```js
describe("Pagination", () => {
    let component: ComponentTester<Pagination>;
    let bindingContext: { pageNumber: number, totalPageCount: number};

    beforeEach(() => {
        bindingContext = { pageNumber: 1, totalPageCount: 7 };
        component = StageComponent
            .withResources<Pagination>("../../src/resources/elements/pagination")
            .inView("<pagination page-number.bind=\"pageNumber\" total-page-count.bind=\"totalPageCount\"></pagination>")
            .boundTo(bindingContext);
    });

    it("pageNumber and pages update when bindingContext value updates", async (done) => {
        await component.create(bootstrap);

        bindingContext.pageNumber = 2;
        setTimeout(() => {
            expect(component.viewModel.pageNumber).toBe(2);
            // ASSERTION IN THE LINE BELLOW FAILS:
            expect(component.viewModel.pages).toStrictEqual([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
            done();
        }, 30);
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        component.dispose();
    });
}
```

Comment: What is the error message you got in the assertion?